# How to use maximum for JS math in CSS-related function

Tags: javascript, css

I've written a function below that allows the user to control the size of certain objects based on a scroll position. The issue is that I don't know how to force the math to stop a minimum or maximum.

In this case, I would like the header width to decrease until it's 25% wide.

```
function EasyPeasyParallax() {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    var currentSize = 100
    $('.header').css({ 'width': (currentSize - Math.min(scrollPos/1.5,2000)) + '%' });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').bind('mousewheel', EasyPeasyParallax);
});
```

I've tried `Math.max()`, but ultimately don't really know how to make this happen.

Any help?

Codepen here: http://codepen.io/bsley/pen/gGyhm

Comment: `(currentSize - Math.min(scrollPos/1.5,2000))` should be `Math.max(currentSize - scrollPos/1.5,25)`

Comment: Consider rephrasing your question's title. There are no CSS events.

Answer (score 0):

I might be barking up wrong tree,  but you could set `min-width` and `max-width` like this, because you are using `.css()` not `.width()`:

```
.header{
  min-width:25%;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var width = (currentSize - Math.min(scrollPos/1.5,2000)),
    min = 25,  // Min percentage
    max = 100; // Max percentage
width = (width < min) ? min: (width > max) ? max : width;
$('.header').css({ 'width': width + '%' });
```

I'm using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) as a shorthand, it basically does this:

```
if(width < min) {
    width = min;
} else {
    if(width > max) {
        width = max;
    } else {
        width = width;
    }
}
```